# Vanilla js function call working in console but not from file

Tags: javascript, function, console

As the title implies i'm unable to have the js script call the function from within the file. randNumGen isn't working. jQuery isn't being used.

```
  var randNumGen = function() {
    var cookie = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)
    return cookie
    debugger;
  }

  randNumGen()
```

Comment: Try `console.log(randoNumGen())`  and see if the output is coming on console.

Comment: Hey that works!

Why is that? Shouldn't the return value of cookie come up?

Comment: The return value doesn't come up on the console. you have to explicitly display the output. So what happens in `console.log(randoNumGen())` is that the value of `cookie` is returned and then `console.log()` displays it in the console. you can also save the return value, like `var a = randNumGen()` and the value of `cookie` will be saved in `a`. On the next line you can do `console.log(a)` and the value of `a` which is now the value of `cookie` will be displayed

Comment: Thanks for the in depth help